# How to limit connections to OpenSSH server to using private keys necessarily with passphrase?

Tags: ssh, security, openssh

Is there any way to configure OpenSSH (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) server to allow private keys necessarily with **passphrase**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you have little control over how the private keys are configured, and you can't detect / enforce any passphrase requirement on them.

You also can't limit the size of the keys without modifying the OpenSSH source itself (i.e. there is no configuration option to achieve a minimum key length limit).

You can limit the type of public keys accepted using the `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes` parameter, but not the length.

> PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes
>
> Specifies the key types that will be accepted for public key
>   authentication as a comma-separated pattern list.  Alternately if
>   the specified value begins with a `+' character, then the specified key
>   types will be appended to  the default set instead of
>   replacing them.  The default for this option is:
>
> ```
>   ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,
>   ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,
>   ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,
>   ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,
>   ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,
>   ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,
>   ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,
>   ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,
>   ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
> ```

Comment: Thank you for answer! Maybe I can enforce only RSA ≥ 2048 bit?